# How can i sort mass action in sales order in magento

Tags: magento

I have created a new mass action in magento back-end on sale > order named as invoice using an extension.
I have created grid.phtml In my module Block/Sale/Order to show my mass action on the back-end in sale order.

grid.phmtl:-

```
<?php
class Iclp_Batchupdate_Block_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
{   
    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        parent::_prepareMassaction();

        // Append new mass action option 
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('batchupdate',array('label' => $this->__('invoice'), 
                  'url'   => $this->getUrl('batchupdate/index/batchinvoice') //this should be the url where there will be mass operation
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Using this my new mass action are shown in the back-end. but now , I am trying to sorting the all mass action according to the alphabets but i can't succeed.

Screen-shot are attached-
[image: massaction screen-shot]

please, suggest me how can I am sorting mass action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to re-arrange the mass action by yourself.

Open to `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php`

Here you have a method named `_prepareMassaction()` in this method we have all mass action written. If you want to show the **cancel** mass action as last option then you have add it after adding all mass action. In below code I have done the same.

```
protected function _prepareMassaction()
{
    $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('order_ids');
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->setUseSelectAll(false);



    if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/hold')) {
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('hold_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Hold'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massHold'),
        ));
    }

    if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/unhold')) {
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('unhold_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Unhold'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massUnhold'),
        ));
    }

    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfinvoices_order', array(
         'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Invoices'),
         'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfinvoices'),
    ));

    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfshipments_order', array(
         'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Packingslips'),
         'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfshipments'),
    ));

    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfcreditmemos_order', array(
         'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Credit Memos'),
         'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfcreditmemos'),
    ));

    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfdocs_order', array(
         'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print All'),
         'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfdocs'),
    ));

    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('print_shipping_label', array(
         'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Shipping Labels'),
         'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order_shipment/massPrintShippingLabel'),
    ));

    if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/cancel')) {
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('cancel_order', array(
            'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Cancel'),
            'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massCancel'),
        ));
    }

    return $this;
}
```

*Note: Please remember do not change core file directly. Override the file in your module.*

**Replace your file by this**

```
 <?php
    class Iclp_Batchupdate_Block_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
    {   
       protected function _prepareMassaction()
        {
            $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('order_ids');
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->setUseSelectAll(false);

            if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/cancel')) {
                $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('cancel_order', array(
                     'label'=> $this->__('Cancel'),
                     'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massCancel'),
                ));
            }

            if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/hold')) {
                $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('hold_order', array(
                     'label'=> $this->__('Hold'),
                     'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massHold'),
                ));
            }

            /**
             * This is your mass action. It's starts from here.
             * Also check this url is working or not
             */
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('batchupdate',array(
                'label' => $this->__('invoice'),
                'url'   => $this->getUrl('batchupdate/index/batchinvoice') //this should be the url where there will be mass operation
            ));
            /**
             * It's end here
             */

            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfdocs_order', array(
                'label'=> $this->__('Print All'),
                'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfdocs'),
            ));

            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfcreditmemos_order', array(
                'label'=> $this->__('Print Credit Memos'),
                'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfcreditmemos'),
            ));

            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfinvoices_order', array(
                 'label'=> $this->__('Print Invoices'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfinvoices'),
            ));

            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfshipments_order', array(
                 'label'=> $this->__('Print Packingslips'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfshipments'),
            ));                

            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('print_shipping_label', array(
                 'label'=> $this->__('Print Shipping Labels'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order_shipment/massPrintShippingLabel'),
            ));

            if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/unhold')) {
                $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('unhold_order', array(
                    'label'=> $this->__('Unhold'),
                    'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massUnhold'),
                ));
            }

            return $this;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am doing it with my module and I do not want to change core file.
how can I do it with my module.

Comment: @Ranjeetsingh I have updated my answer please replace your code by my code. Please correct the code indent by yourself.

Comment: I don't want this . according to your code all the mass action are generated again but I only want to sort the mass action.

Comment: I am not generating mass action again. In my code i have just overridden the `_prepareMassaction` of Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid. What do you think in your code what does this means `parent::_prepareMassaction();`.

Comment: It's working fine but actually my client's requirement doesn't allow me to override the file. is there another way ??

Comment: Oh.. but I have not overwritten the file I am using your module block class only.. check the class name and there is no other way of doing it..